# scp: How to copy only the last 10% of a file?

Tags: linux, rsync, scp

I have a relatively large log file (46M) on a vServer, of which I'm only interested in the most recent part.

How can I download only the last 10% of the file?

The server is running Debian and I'm using Ubuntu locally.

Comment: You tagged the post with `rsync`. Why don't you just download the whole file and keep using `rsync` to periodically update it from the server? (Log files also compress well, so with `rsync -z` you'll just need to download 4-5 MB *for the entire log file*.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First get the size of the remote file in bytes:

```
$ ssh user@host 'stat -c%s FILENAME'    
50000
```

Calculate 10% of that number, and copy the last ten percent:

```
$ ssh user@host 'tail -c 5000 FILENAME' > DESTINATION
```

Comment: Excellent. :) Does `stat -c%s` have any advantage over `du -b`?

Comment: I guess one could even combine those commands to decrease readability and save one SSH connection: `ssh user@host 'f=FILENAME; tail -c $(($(stat -c%s $f)/10)) $f' > DESTINATION`

Comment: @n.st: They both end up using the same `stat()` syscall, which is fast, although `du` also examines all mounted filesystems using `stat()` before the actual file. But that's not a difference in practice. ⫽ However, if you need to get just the bytes (like in the one-liner in your last comment), then running `stat` will be easier because it doesn't output the unnecessary filename, making the one-liner shorter than it would have been with `du -b | sed ...`.

Comment: Can similar thing be done for upload ? Like upload only some bytes to server, instead of entire file ?