# Upload only few bytes from a file to the SFTP

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, upload

I have a use case wherein I need to upload only some bytes(can be in GB) of the file to SFTP server rather than the entire file. With SFTP PUT command the entire file gets uploaded, instead of some bytes.

I do not want to read the file and then make a smaller file out of that and then upload that entire smaller file to SFTP. This can be very memory intensive if the bytes to be uploaded are in GB. So, discarding this option.

Is there any other way to do this using SFTP(may be using -o to use ssh options) command. Perhaps something like [scp: How to copy only the last 10% of a file?](https://superuser.com/questions/633299/scp-how-to-copy-only-the-last-10-of-a-file)

pls suggest

Comment: Does it need to be SFTP specifically, rather than some other "file transfer over SSH" mechanism?

Comment: Yes, It is SFTP.  but if ssh also does that, I was thinking give that as ssh_options in the SFTP command

Comment: SSH alone doesn't do that; it's only a transport. You can however directly stream data over SSH from a local command to a remote command (e.g "dd if= | ssh host dd of="), which is also how tools such as rsync work. To be clear, what you're asking for is certainly _possible_ using the SFTP protocol, but may require programming a custom SFTP client (e.g. via python-paramiko) instead of using any existing SFTP app. On the other hand, it can be done in 1 shell command if the remote side runs standard Linux and SFTP is not a requirement.

Comment: @user1686 I have a hard requirement of using commands only and no library(like paramiko). Can any command help me to read some bytes directly into SFTP file rather than storing locally

Comment: No, not that I know of (although one could argue that `/usr/bin/python -c "import paramiko; ..."` is, technically, only a command) What is the origin of your requirement?

Comment: Can we do something like ssh <sftp_host> and then do the how the rsync works..may be something on those lines if that's possible

Comment: Well, that's what I'm asking _you_ about. Sure you could do that, but then it wouldn't be SFTP. Hence the question about whether SFTP is required or not.

Comment: @user1686 can you help me with the ssh command..WIll check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard OpenSSH `sftp` client doesn't support partial uploads.

If the server is running regular Linux, then you can directly pipe data to an SSH connection without using SFTP:

```
$ tail -c 2G ~/bigfile | ssh myserver "cat > smallchunk"
```

(Here `tail -c 2G` is just an example command that outputs the last 2 GB of the file. Replace it as appropriate – if you want the first X bytes then you'll want to use `head`, if you want want bytes from the middle use some combination of `head|tail` or maybe `dd`.)

Optional improvement: You can insert 'pv' to display a progress bar.

```
$ tail -c 2G ~/bigfile | pv | ssh myserver "cat > smallchunk"
```

If you *do* require SFTP, then the `lftp` client can be tricked into achieving this by uploading a *named* pipe:

1. Create a named pipe somewhere:

   ```
   $ mkfifo /tmp/pipe
   ```
2. Run a command that gets whichever bytes you want, and writes them to the named pipe:

   ```
   $ tail -c 2G ~/bigfile > /tmp/pipe &
   ```

   The command will immediately be paused as soon as it tries to write to the pipe. (This works exactly like the `|` nameless pipe in the previous example – the writing process gets paused until the reading process reads everything out of the pipe, 4kB at a time. Hence the `&` to let it happen in background.)
3. Ask lftp to upload the pipe:

   ```
   $ lftp sftp://myserver
   lftp> put -o smallchunk /tmp/pipe
   2G bytes transferred
   ```

---

---

For clarity regarding pipes: Here's example 1 again...

```
$ tail -c 2G ~/bigfile | ssh myserver "cat > smallchunk"
```

...and here's example 1 rewritten to use 'mkfifo' from example 2:

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/pipe
$ tail -c 2G ~/bigfile > /tmp/pipe &
$ ssh myserver "cat > smallchunk" < /tmp/pipe
```

Both of these work the same way: they use a pipe connecting one writer process to one reader. Both named and nameless pipes have a 4 kB buffer; every time it fills up, the writer is paused until the reader gets the data.

Comment: One question - doesn't the tail command consume heavy memory (for eg-2GB) or it does not write to disk ?

Comment: The command writes to a _pipe,_ which is a special object that only looks like a file but doesn't have any storage space allocated to it. Pipes do have a small in-memory buffer, but it is only 4 kB – as soon as it fills up, further writes get paused until the buffer is read out. This way you won't run out of memory, as the data is not stored anywhere – it's produced and consumed in parallel.

Comment: (Both the `|` nameless pipe and the `mkfifo` named pipe work exactly the same way – both have a writer, a reader, and a 4 kB buffer in the middle. The name or lack thereof is literally the only difference.)

Comment: What happens to the /tmp/pipe after the upload. Do we have to delete it or it gets deleted automatically ?

Comment: Named pipes are reusable, so after you've created one with mkfifo it remains until you manually delete it. (Although the memory buffer is automatically deallocated as soon as both the writer and reader close their file-handles.) A named pipe doesn't really occupy any disk space, so you can keep it there for multiple uploads if you want.